# Restrict Access to Active Directory based on IP range

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I need to restrict access to Active Directory Application based on fixed IP Address range. For this, I saw an option in configuration of Active Directory, to add IP address range.

[image: IP Address range option]

I tried this way to restrict IP address, and tried to access Active Directory from another IP address(not in this range), and it got access to Active Directory.

Is there any other way to do this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-known-networks) and refer to explanation on the portal :

> > Adding your organization's public address ranges ensures that ,going forward , users signing in from these ip addresses will NOT be flagged in the "Sign ins from multiple geographies" and "Sign ins from IP addresses with suspicious activity" reports .

So Adding your organization's public address ranges can't be used to restrict access to Active Directory Application based on IP Address range . To achieve that, you could try to use location based access rules(need Azure Active Directory Premium), please refer to below config steps:

1. In the configure page of the app you want to config the access rules :
   [image]
2. Enable the access rules ,choose **Block access when not at work**(Users trying to access the application from outside your corporate network will not be able to access the application.) ,click the link to edit your work network location :
   [image]
3. Set trusted ips in the service setting tab:
   [image]
   4.Click save button both on service setting page and app configure page .
   5.When you want to access above app using a mistrustful ip, you will be blocked :
   [image]

Comment: Thanks Nan Yu. Its really helpful. (Y)
Just tell me is it necessary for the Active Directory to be premium to restrict IP based access?

Comment: Yes, location based access rules need premium version

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for quick response.

Comment: Hi Nan Yu, I've got license for Active Directory and it is premium now. But I am not seeing any option for enabling access rules in app configuration. Do I need to so something else too?

Comment: @Sundas Mushtaq ,have you assigned the Azure AD Premium plan to the user you want to manage the azure ad ?

Comment: yes I have assigned premium plan to AD and I have done the above configuration. I also have specified the IP Address range for which the two step verification will be skipped. Now I am accessing this Active Directory Application with Asp.net code to get AccessToken. And I am successfully getting the AccessToken from non-trusted IP which should not happen. What else do i need to do in this case?

Comment: Have you set"block access when not work"? and confirm the ip address you set  the same as the ip address(ipaddr claim) in access token .

Comment: Yes. I have checked this option. And have set an IP there.

Comment: I am accessing Azure Active Directory to get Access Token using AD App's Client ID and Client Secret in C# VSTO Outlook Add in project. I want to allow some defined subnets to access AD using this Outlook Addin. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Here is sample code 
`private static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string scope)
{
var clientId = AppConfig.GetConfigValue(Constants.ClientId);
var clientSecret = AppConfig.GetConfigValue(Constants.ClientSecret);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
AuthenticationResult authenticatedCredentials = null;
                authenticatedCredentials = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredentials);}`

Comment: When you sign in the application which protect by azure ad , azure ad can check visitor's public ip address(external ip address) , if you check the access token , you will find the ip address in the token(ipaddr claim) is not the same as your ip address in sub-net .If you want to check that , you need to write your own logical operation to check the allowed Internal ip address , that is not much related to AAD ,as we discussed in your another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762529/restrict-azure-active-directory-application-access-based-on-ip-addresses/42779688#42779688)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138084/discussion-between-sundas-mushtaq-and-nan-yu-msft).