# Restrict Azure Active Directory Application Access based on IP addresses

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory

I need to restrict access to Azure Active Directory Application. Just allowed sub-nets can access Active Directory Application. Where can I configure that IP range in AD application that will restrict access for other sub-nets to that application?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% sure if you can't do this, but I would say that it would be kind of easy to get around such a restriction by e.g. getting an authorization code from an allowed subnet and then moving that with the nonce etc. to a machine anywhere else and I could be signed in. You really have to check this in your app in the end anyway.

Comment: I agree with @juunas, your app needs to check it on every request anyway, so no need to do anything special AAD related.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK , Azure AD can't config your app access rule base on the sub-net address range currently. If the server which app published and your sub-net are in same local network ,in the application , you could check visitor's private ip address(
Internal ip address) to meet the requirement, you could try retrieving a visitor's IP address from the Request Headers by using the UserHostAddress property of the HttpRequest object : Request.UserHostAddress .